# How can I display these records specific to the data they contain?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am building a page that displays information about reports. These reports contain the date, name, and a small description.

So far, I have been able to pull all of the reports from my database in descending chronological order. Print_r() displays this:

```
Array ( [year] => 2024 [name] => 2024-05-25_601832524.pdf [date] => 2024-05-25 [description] => tr7 )
Array ( [year] => 2024 [name] => 2024-05-13_1778477336.pdf [date] => 2024-05-13 [description] => tr6 )
Array ( [year] => 2024 [name] => 2024-05-22_1352917456.pdf [date] => 2024-05-22 [description] => tr7 )
Array ( [year] => 2022 [name] => 2022-02-19_1728056762.pdf [date] => 2022-02-19 [description] => tr3 )
Array ( [year] => 2022 [name] => 2022-05-19_1307066849.pdf [date] => 2022-05-19 [description] => tr5 )
```

Essentially, I need to separate these records by the year (which I will display as a heading) and then iterate through every record of that given year, displaying the data of the record before moving on to the next year's heading and records.

Unfortunately, how many total records or records per year cannot be determined. Neither can the number of unique years as these values will change regularly. (when new reports are added to the db or old ones are deleted).

I have not posted my attempted solutions as they consist of 2 days' worth of various attempts to instantiate a new `$$year[]` each time the [year] of the next record in the stack is different from the previous one.

[image: Example of what I am trying to do]

**Edit:** To clarify, I have a 2D array that contains all the records of reports on my db. I need to iterate through this array and sort every record into separate arrays corresponding to the `[year]` value of every record.

In order to avoid any ambiguity, I have included an example:

Sorting from the array of records presented above, I would like to sort the array like so:

```
Years[]= ([0]=>2024[],[1]=> 2022[]);
2022[] =([0]=>([year] => 2022 [name] => 2022-02-19_1728056762.pdf [date] => 2022-02-19 [description] => tr3 ), [1]=>( [year] => 2022 [name] => 2022-05-19_1307066849.pdf [date] => 2022-05-19 [description] => tr5 ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume some aspects, since no code example is provided.

> 1) You said these results came from the database, but in the prin_r results i see multiple standalone arrays, i assume the print_r is called inside a loop structure
>
> 2) You want to sseperate these records by year and want to retain all data/elemtns of the array

This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
 $testData = [
        [
            'year' => 2024,
            'name' => '2024-05-25_601832524.pdf',
            'date' => '2024-05-25',
            'description' => 'tr7'
        ],
        [
            'year' => 2023,
            'name' => '2024-05-25_601832524.pdf',
            'date' => '2024-05-25',
            'description' => 'tr7'
        ],
        [
            'year' => 2023,
            'name' => '2024-05-25_601832524.pdf',
            'date' => '2024-05-25',
            'description' => 'tr7'
        ],
        [
            'year' => 2020,
            'name' => 'YoloSwagEasterEgg.pdf',
            'date' => '2024-05-25',
            'description' => 'tr7'
        ]
    ];

    $dataseperatedByYear = [];

    foreach ($testData as $record) {
        $dataseperatedByYear[$record['year']][] = $record;
    }

    print_r($dataseperatedByYear);
    die();
```

Comment: Will this not save every record to a nested array separately instead of grouping all $record s that have the same year?

Comment: it will not group all records [look at my assumptions mentioned] do you want to only have one name/description per year?

Comment: No, I want it to store all records that have the year x in array x and all records with year y in array y and so on.